# How to add second group of variables to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a second group of variables to a JavaScript file that are in a different section of a browser's form. What is there now and works is:

```
var first_container = $('.first-section-of-form');
var name_a = first_container.find(':input[id*="edit-panes-first-section-one"]');
var name_b = first_container.find(':input[id*="edit-panes-first-section-two"]');
```

What I need to add are the second set

```
var second_container = $('.second-section-of-form');
var name_c = second_container.find(':input[id*="edit-panes-second-section-one"]');
var name_d = second_container.find(':input[id*="edit-panes-second-section-two"]');
```

I tried this:

```
var first_container = {
    $('.first-section-of-form');
    var name_a = first_container.find(':input[id*="edit-panes-first-section-one"]');
    var name_b = first_container.find(':input[id*="edit-panes-first-section-two"]');
};
var second_container = {
    $('.second-section-of-form');
    var name_c = second_container.find(':input[id*="edit-panes-second-section-one"]');
    var name_d = second_container.find(':input[id*="edit-panes-second-section-two"]');
};
```

Which threw the following error:

> uncaught syntax error at =>   $('.first-section-of-form');

From inspecting the elements in Chrome Developer tools I know that the id and input fields are correct and taken from there (not the exact ones listed for examples)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear from the example what you are trying to do.  However, you most certainly cannot create a javascript object like that.

Comment: I think it'd be helpful to those answering if you could make a jsfiddle of the code you're trying to create, so we have more of an idea of how to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
var $first_section = $('.first-section-of-form');
var $second_section = $('.second-section-of-form');

var first_container = {
   name_a: $first_section.find(':input[id*="edit-panes-first-section-one"]'),
   name_b: $first_section.find(':input[id*="edit-panes-first-section-two"]')
};

var second_container = {
   name_c: $second_section.find(':input[id*="edit-panes-second-section-one"]'),
   name_d: $second_section.find(':input[id*="edit-panes-second-section-two"]')
};
```

You might want to read up on Javascript Objects. They act sort of like hashes, maps or dictionaries (depending on which languages you are used to).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: Yes - that worked - and now I have other definition issues to correct in the file - thanks for the link - I am not familiar with JavaScript and JQuery beyond what looks familiar to me on sight and then - I'll screw up the syntax every time.  I am closer now thanks to you !!